# Can gcc output C code after preprocessing?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm using an open source library which seems to have lots of preprocessing directives to support many languages other than C. So that I can study what the library is doing I'd like to see the C code that I'm compiling after preprocessing, more like what I'd write.

Can gcc (or any other tool commonly available in Linux) read this library but output C code that has the preprocessing converted to whatever and is also readable by a human?

Comment: The preprocessed code wont have any preprocessor directives anymore but I am fairly sure it will be much much less readable than before being preprocessed...

Comment: @AlexW - That depends *entirely* on how horribly the people writing the code abused the preprocessor.

Comment: Please consider changing your accepted answer here.  `gcc -E` is more useful than having to rewrite the line to make it work with `cpp`.

Comment: [Ciro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-%e6%96%b0%e7%96%86%e5%86%8d%e6%95%99%e8%82%b2%e8%90%a5%e5%85%ad%e5%9b%9b%e4%ba%8b%e4%bb%b6%e6%b3%95%e8%bd%ae%e5%8a%9f%e9%83%9d%e6%b5%b7%e4%b8%9c) provided a very good [`gcc -save-temps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55477371/4123703) I suggest to take a look.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Yes. Pass gcc the `-E` option. This will output preprocessed source code.

Comment: If your compiler commands already has a parameter like `-o something.o` you may also want to change it to `-o something.i`. Otherwise the preprocessed output will be in the `.o` file.

Comment: @TorKlingberg Can I do this for multiple files at a time?

Comment: @user2808264 `gcc -E file1.c file2.c ...`

Comment: Is there an option for the preprocessor to expand only macroses like `#define SIZE 1000` or `#ifdef Something #endif` but not `#include <other_file.h>`

I want to see a preprocessed file but without external functions imported into a single file.

Answer (score 80):

`cpp` is the preprocessor.

Run `cpp filename.c` to output the preprocessed code, or better, redirect it to a file with
`cpp filename.c > filename.preprocessed`.

Comment: I think this is the best answer because it demonstrates cpp directly. Linux systems (at least Manjaro) seem to have -E by default too. I get the same results from this command either way. `diff` turns up no difference in the files. This is also looks like a useful way to preprocess the code looking for errors in your macros. Great question and a great answer (IALCTHW).

Comment: @lee8oi I was curious what IALCTHW meant but my attempt to web search for it only resulted in this page as a search result. What does that acronym mean? I am quite curious.

Answer (score 38):

**`-save-temps`**

The advantage of this option over `-E` is that it is easy to add it to any build script, without interfering much in the build itself:

```
gcc -save-temps -c -o main.o main.c
```

main.c

```
#define INC 1

int myfunc(int i) {
    return i + INC;
}
```

and now, besides the normal output `main.o`, the current working directory also contains the following files:

- `main.i` is the desired prepossessed file containing:

  ```
  # 1 "main.c"
  # 1 "<built-in>"
  # 1 "<command-line>"
  # 31 "<command-line>"
  # 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
  # 32 "<command-line>" 2
  # 1 "main.c"


  int myfunc(int i) {
      return i + 1;
  }
  ```
- `main.s` is a bonus :-) and contains the generated assembly:

  ```
      .file   "main.c"
      .text
      .globl  myfunc
      .type   myfunc, @function
  myfunc:
  .LFB0:
      .cfi_startproc
      pushq   %rbp
      .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
      .cfi_offset 6, -16
      movq    %rsp, %rbp
      .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
      movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
      movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
      addl    $1, %eax
      popq    %rbp
      .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
      ret
      .cfi_endproc
  .LFE0:
      .size   myfunc, .-myfunc
      .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0"
      .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
  ```

Docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-save-temps

**`-save-temps=obj`**

If you want to do it for a large number of files, consider using instead:

```
-save-temps=obj
```

which saves the intermediate files to the same directory as the `-o` object output instead of the current working directory, thus avoiding potential basename conflicts.

For example:

```
gcc -save-temps -c -o out/subdir/main.o subdir/main.c
```

leads to the creation of files:

```
out/subdir/main.i
out/subdir/main.o
out/subdir/main.s
```

Clearly an Apple plot to take over the world.

**`-save-temps -v`**

Another cool thing about this option is if you add `-v`:

```
gcc -save-temps -c -o main.o -v main.c
```

it actually shows the explicit files being used instead of ugly temporaries under `/tmp`, so it is easy to know exactly what is going on, which includes the preprocessing / compilation / assembly steps:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu main.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fpch-preprocess -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o main.i
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/cc1 -fpreprocessed main.i -quiet -dumpbase main.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip main.o -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o main.s
as -v --64 -o main.o main.s
```

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) amd64, GCC 8.3.0.

**CMake predefined targets**

CMake automatically provides a targets for the preprocessed file:

```
make help
```

shows us that we can do:

```
make main.i
```

and that target runs:

```
Preprocessing C source to CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.i
/usr/bin/cc    -E /home/ciro/bak/hello/main.c > CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.i
```

so the file can be seen at `CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.i`

Tested on cmake 3.16.1.

Comment: Much more elegant than -E because I can just add -save-temps to CFLAGS without changing the overall behaviour of the build script. Thank you!

Comment: This is indeed very useful, and -E is very convenient for single files.

Comment: Incredibly useful! thanks!

Comment: And for make, one can do: `make CFLAGS+="--save-temps"`

Comment: `make main.i` is the easiest way for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

I'm using gcc as a preprocessor (for html files.) It does just what you want. It expands "#--" directives, then outputs a readable file. (NONE of the other C/HTML preprocessors I've tried do this- they concatenate lines, choke on special characters, etc.)  Asuming you have gcc installed, the command line is:

gcc -E -x c -P -C -traditional-cpp code_before.cpp  >  code_after.cpp

(Doesn't have to be 'cpp'.) There's an excellent description of this usage at http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/cpre.html.

The "-traditional-cpp" preserves whitespace & tabs.

Comment: Many thanks, this is very helpful to generate python cffi cdef!

Comment: cpre article link https://jkorpela.fi/html/cpre.html I am guessing this is what is filling the suggested edit queue...

Answer (score 12):

Run:

```
gcc -E <file>.c
```

or

```
g++ -E <file>.cpp
```

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we have a file as Message.cpp or a .c file

**Steps 1:** Preprocessing (Argument `-E`)

```
g++ -E .\Message.cpp > P1
```

P1 file generated has expanded macros and header file contents and comments are stripped off.

**Step 2:** Translate Preprocessed file to assembly (Argument `-S`). This task is done by compiler

```
g++ -S .\Message.cpp
```

An assembler (ASM) is generated (Message.s). It has all the assembly code.

**Step 3:** Translate assembly code to Object code. Note: Message.s was generated in Step2.

```
g++ -c .\Message.s
```

An Object file with the name Message.o is generated. It is the binary form.

**Step 4:** Linking the object file. This task is done by linker

```
g++ .\Message.o -o MessageApp
```

An exe file MessageApp.exe is generated here.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//This a sample program
int main()
{
  cout << "Hello" << endl;
  cout << PQR(P,K) ;
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A little late!  You can skip steps 2 and 3 -- g++/gcc recognize .i files as preprocessed source code.  First, #define the PQR macro in the source file.  Then:
**Step 1:** g++ -E Message.cpp > Message.i
**Step 2:** g++ Message.i > MessageApp