# C/C++: source file after preprocessing-Diab compiler?

Tags: c++, c

**source.c** *--(preprocessing)-->* **temp_source.c** *--(compiling)-->* **source.elf** --*(linking)*--> **source.exe**

How to view **temp_source.c** ?

(I just assume that this file name temp_source.c)

**Edit**: I'm using Diab compiler.

Comment: If you are using g++, try '-E' flag.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900870/can-gcc-output-c-code-after-preprocessing

Comment: I downvoted because question doesn't mention what compiler is being used. This results in people guessing unnecessarily. Please edit the question to add missing information.

Comment: I couldn't decide whether to downvote because you failed to provide adequate detail about what compiler you were using, or whether you failed to expend a minimal amount of effort searching for the answer yourself. The top two related questions answer this for [GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900870/can-gcc-output-c-code-after-preprocessing) and [MSVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/how-do-i-see-a-c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing-in-visual-studio).

Comment: Flagged as unclear what you're asking. Also, `compiler-construction` is hardly an appropriate tag for something this basic.

Comment: Most compilers have a flag to stop after the pre-processing step -- check your compilers documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Command line interface to Microsoft Visual C++ can be used to output the preprocessed file as :

```
/E: preprocess to stdout (similar to GCC's -E option)
/P: preprocess to file
/EP: preprocess to stdout without #line directives
```

Answer (score 0):

The gcc preprocessor is called cpp

```
$ cpp -o preprossed_temp.c temp.c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use GCC, just write:

```
gcc -E source.c -o temp_source.c
```

Answer (score 0):

**On Windows**

Compiler will create a intermediate file with default extension (.i)

```
cl /P source.c
```

Compiler will redirect to stdout

```
cl /E source.c

cl /E source.c > source.txt
```

**On Linux**

```
$gcc -E source.c > source.txt
```