# How #define preprocessor really works in C

Tags: android, c++, c

Please consider the following codes

```
#define FIRSTNAME ""
#define SECONDNAME "JOHN"
# define PATHSAVE(a) func(strcat(strcpy(tmpFileName, appDir), a))
int main() {
  PATHSAVE(FIRSTNAME SECONDNAME);
}
```

By analyzing I found out that value "John" is passed to the function PATHSAVE.
By I couldnt understand why two parameters are used in this function PATHSAVE(FIRSTNAME SECONDNAME)

Comment: You are not passing 2 parameters. You are passing one parameter which is the result of concatenation of `FIRSTNAME` and `SECONDNAME`. Different parameters are delimited by comma (`,`).

Comment: Sending this [through the preprocessor *only*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900870/can-gcc-output-c-code-after-preprocessing), and examining the output would probably answer your question.

Comment: Looks like it is an example of string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PATHSAVE(FIRSTNAME SECONDNAME);
```

will expand to PATHSAVE("JOHN")  as the preprocessor will concatinate the 2 strings together.

This will then be further expanded to

```
func(strcat(strcpy(tmpFileName, appDir), "JOHN"))
```

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote will be expanded as follows

```
func(strcat(strcpy(tmpFileName, appDir), "" "JOHN"));
                                         ^^ ^^^^^^
                                         || ||||||
                                         || SECONDNAME
                                         ||
                                         FIRSTNAME
```

Passing two parameters to a macro require them to be separated by `,` and not by a space

Answer (score 1):

You can use the c pre processor if you want to know what is going on.

I pasted your code in a file named ex.c, here is the output of:

cpp ex.c

```
# 1 "ex.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "ex.c"



int main() {
  func(strcat(strcpy(tmpFileName, appDir), "" "JOHN"));
}
```