# Get preprocessor output from C through MATLAB mex

Tags: c, matlab, gcc, mex

I want to get the preprocessor output when compiling my c-code through mex of MATLAB using MinGW64 Compiler (C) so using gcc (right?).
From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900870/can-gcc-output-c-code-after-preprocessing) I got that you can do this with pure gcc passing the option -E to gcc.
However I installed gcc through MATLAB app and therefore cannot access it through command line (would also appreciate a command how to do that, without reinstalling MinGW64 and setting it up manually for use with MATLAB).

I tried to do the following assuming that compiler flags are the right way to pass the argument:

```
mex -c grampc_run.c -I../../include -I../include COMPFLAGS='$COMPFLAGS -E'
```

This just results in the creation of the object file.

Comment: Just a side node:
I can do this using Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt with:
cl my_file.c /P /I"C:\...\include" /I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" /out:my_file.i

--> \P is the right flag in VS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COMPFLAGS` is used by the MSCV compiler. The GCC compiler loos at `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` (for C and C++ compilation, respectively). See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#btw193g-1). Thus, you should use the following syntax:

```
mex -c grampc_run.c -I../../include -I../include CFLAGS='$CFLAGS -E'
```

You might also want to add the `-v` option to `mex`. GCC puts the preprocessor output to the standard output, which `mex` might not show you. With `-v` it does show you all the output.