# Is there a easy way to insert header files on the C code (without using include)?

Tags: c, struct, c-header

I was coding for a college project, and it is practically finished. But my amazing teacher placed the condition that it would only be possible to send 1 .c file, and i have one header that i used to organize some functions of the code. I am having a lot of trouble making this in one file. Here is the code:

```
#include <string.h> //Defining one variable type, macro, and various functions for manipulating arrays of characters.
#include "221037581.h" //Defining my own header to import especif functions.
#include <stdlib.h> //Defining the standart library.


#define REG_USI 1 //Register plant
#define REG_CONS 2 //Register consumer
#define REG_CONT 3 //Register contract
#define CHECK_USI 4 //Check plant
#define CHECK_CONS 5 //Check consumer
#define DEL_USI 6 //Delete plant
#define DEL_CONS 7 //Delete consumer
#define EXIT 8 //Exit

#define SIZ_NAME 100 //Defining maximum name size
#define CPF_MIN 11 //Defining cpf size
#define SIZ_ID 18 //Defining id size
#define MAX_SIZE 100 //Defining maximum size for database
#define SIZ_DATE 8 //Defining date size
#define SIZ_CNPJ 14 //Defining cnpj size

#define DB_NAME 'n' //Defining name database
#define DB_ID 'i' //Defining ID database
#define DB_USER 'u' //Defining user database
#define DB_plant 'p' //Defining plant database
#define DB_CONTRACT 'c' //Defining contract database



int main_menu();  //Defining menu function 
void r_u(); //Defining register plant function
void r_c(); //Defining register consumer function
void r_contrat(); //Defining register contract function
void c_u(); //Defining check plant function
void c_c(); //Defining check consumer function
void d_u(); //Defining delete plant function
void d_c(); //Defining delete consumer function


void info_plant(char id[SIZ_ID]); //Defining function to consult the plant and show how much MWs still is usable.
void info_user(char id[SIZ_ID]); //Defining function to consult user and your contracts




int main() //Main function
{
    int n; 

    FILE *data_base;

    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_PP, "r"); //Opening database
    if (data_base == NULL) {
      data_base = fopen(DATABASE_PP, "w+");
      fprintf(data_base,"0xxxxxxxxxxxxx\nName :3\nxxxxxxxx\n1.000000\n");
    } 
    fclose(data_base); //Closing database
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_CONTRACT, "r"); //Opening contract database
    if (data_base == NULL) { 
      data_base = fopen(DATABASE_CONTRACT, "w+");//Opening contract database
      fprintf(data_base,"0xxxxxxxxxxxxx\n0xxxxxxxxxx\nxxxxxxxx\n1.000000\n");
    }
    fclose(data_base); //Closing database

    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_USER, "r"); //Opening user database
    if (data_base == NULL) {
      data_base = fopen(DATABASE_USER, "w+"); //Opening user database
      fprintf(data_base,"0xxxxxxxxxxxxx\nName :3\n");
    }
    fclose(data_base); //Closing database
    n = main_menu(); 
    if(n == EXIT){
        printf("\nThanks for using my software\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main_menu(){ //Start menu function
    int escolha; 
    clean(); //Clean screen function
    for(;;){
        printf("\nPHOTOVOLTAIC ENERGY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM - PEMS\n\n 1 -> Register plant.\n 2 -> Register Consumer.\n 3 -> Register a contract between consumer and plant.\n 4 -> Consult registered plant.\n 5 -> Consult registered consumer.\n 6 -> Delete plant.\n 7 -> Delete consumer.\n 8 -> EXIT.\n\nMake your choice: "); //Menu statement.
      scanf(" %d",&escolha); //Recieve choice from user.
      switch(escolha){ //Options
        case REG_USI: //Register plant.
          clean();
          r_u();
          break;
        case REG_CONS: //Register consumer.
          clean();
          r_c();
          break;
        case REG_CONT: //Register contract.
          clean();
          r_contrat();
          break;
        case CHECK_USI: //Consult plant.
          clean();
          c_u();
          break;
        case CHECK_CONS: //Consult consumer.
          clean();
          c_c();
          break;
        case DEL_USI: //Delete plant.
          clean();
          d_u();
          break;
        case DEL_CONS: //Delete consumer.
          clean();
          d_c();
          break;
        case EXIT: //Exit from software.
          return EXIT;
          break;
        default:
          clean();
          printf("caracter inválido!");
          break;
      }
    }
    return escolha;
}

void r_u(){ //Register plant function.
  char cnpj[SIZ_ID],name[SIZ_NAME],data[SIZ_DATE]; //Defining structs.
  int aux, n;
  float mw;
  clean();
  for(;;){ //Function to define the name of the power plant.
    printf("\n Register plant:\n\n");
    printf(" Type the name of power plant: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",name);
    n = id_check(name);
    if(n == TRUE){
      clean();
      printf("\nInsert a valid name.\n");
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  clean();
  for(;;){ //Function to define CNPJ of power plant.
    printf("\n Register plant:\n\n");
    printf(" Type the CNPJ of power plant: ");
    scanf(" %s",cnpj);
    n = id_check(cnpj);
    if(n == FALSE){ //CNPJ verifications.
      clean();
      printf("\nInsert a valid identification.\n");
    }
    else{ //Consulting if cnpj already on plants database.
      n = id_check_database(cnpj,DB_plant);
      if(n == TRUE){
        clean();
        printf("\nIndentification already used.\n");
      }else{ //Consulting if cnpj already on users database.
        n = id_check_database(cnpj,DB_USER);
        if(n == TRUE){
          clean();
          printf("\nAlready in use by a user.\n");
        }else{
          clean();
          break;
        }
      }
      }
      
  }
  clean(); //Clean screen function.
  for(;;){ //Registering date from power plant.
    printf("\n Register plant:\n\n");
    printf("Type the date from the plant beginning operations (DDMMAAAA): ");
    scanf(" %s",data);
    n = date_check(data); // Date verification function.
    if(n == FALSE){
      clean();
      printf("\nInsert a valid date.\n");
    }
    else{
      clean();
      break;
    }
  }
  clean();
  for(;;){ //MGw power plant.
    printf("\n Register plant:\n\n");
    printf(" Type the potency of the power plant in MGw: ");
    scanf(" %f",&mw);
    if(mw <= 0){ //Checking if the power of the plant is valid.
      clean();
      printf("\nType a valid potency.\n");
    }
    else{
      clean();
      break;
    }
  }
  POWERP usina;
  if(strlen(cnpj) == CNPJ_MIN){ //organizing cnpj
    usina.cnpj[0] = cnpj[0];
    usina.cnpj[1] = cnpj[1];
    usina.cnpj[2] = cnpj[2];
    usina.cnpj[3] = cnpj[3];
    usina.cnpj[4] = cnpj[4];
    usina.cnpj[5] = cnpj[5];
    usina.cnpj[6] = cnpj[6];
    usina.cnpj[7] = cnpj[7];
    usina.cnpj[8] = cnpj[8];
    usina.cnpj[9] = cnpj[9];
    usina.cnpj[10] = cnpj[10];
    usina.cnpj[11] = cnpj[11];
    usina.cnpj[12] = cnpj[12];
    usina.cnpj[13] = cnpj[13];
    usina.cnpj[14] = '\0';
  }

  if (strlen(data) == DATE_MIN) { //ignore this (sad try)
    usina.date[0] = data[0];
    usina.date[1] = data[1];
    usina.date[2] = data[2];
    usina.date[3] = data[3];
    usina.date[4] = data[4];
    usina.date[5] = data[5];
    usina.date[6] = data[6];
    usina.date[7] = data[7];
    usina.date[8] = '\0';
  }

  // Preparing for implement on database
  for(aux = 0; aux <= SIZ_NAME; aux++){
    if(name[aux] == '\0'){
      usina.name[aux] = '\0';
      break;
    }
    usina.name[aux] = name[aux];
  }
  usina.mw = mw;
  power_plant_db_add(usina);
  //printf("%s, %s\n", usina.cnpj, cnpj);
  clean();
  printf("Power plant registered with sucess!");
}
void r_c(){ //Function for user register.

  USER usuario;
  char id[SIZ_ID],name[SIZ_NAME]; 
  int n, aux;
  clean();
  for(;;){ //Looping for recieve username.
    printf("\n Register user:\n\n");
    printf(" Type the name of the user: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",usuario.name); //Recieving the username.
    n = id_check(usuario.name); //Fuctions that it is responsable for name validations.
    if(n == TRUE){
      clean(); 
      printf("\nInsert a valid name\n");
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  clean();
  for(;;){  //Looping for recieve cpf or cnpj from user.
    printf("\n Register user:\n\n");
    printf(" Type cpf or cnpj from user. ");
    scanf(" %s",id);
    n = id_check(id); //Cpf and cnpj verification.
    if(n == FALSE){
      clean();
      printf("\nInsert a valid identification. \n");
    }
    else{ 
      n = id_check_database(id,DB_USER); //Check if identification its already in use.
      if(n == TRUE){
        clean();
        printf("\nIndentification already in use.\n");
      }else{
        n = id_check_database(id,DB_plant);
        if(n == TRUE){
          clean();
          printf("\nIndentification already in use by the power plant.\n"); //Check if identification its already in use.
        }else{
          clean();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //Adding at data base.

  if(strlen(id) == CNPJ_MIN && (id[3] >= NUMERO_MIN && id[3]<=NUMERO_MAX)){ //organizing cnpj
    usuario.id[0] = id[0]; //Unnecessary
    usuario.id[1] = id[1];
    usuario.id[2] = id[2];
    usuario.id[3] = id[3];
    usuario.id[4] = id[4];
    usuario.id[5] = id[5];
    usuario.id[6] = id[6];
    usuario.id[7] = id[7];
    usuario.id[8] = id[8];
    usuario.id[9] = id[9];
    usuario.id[10] = id[10];
```

And this is the header file that i want put on the .c file:

```
#define SIZ_ID 18 //Defining id size
#define MAX_SIZE 100 //Defining maximum size for database
#define SIZ_DATE 8 //Defining date size
#define SIZ_CNPJ 14 //Defining cnpj size
#define MAX_SIZE 100
#define FLOAT_SIZE 10
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

#define CPF_MIN 11 //Defining cpf size
#define CPF_MAX 14 //Defining max cpf size (unusable)
#define CNPJ_MIN 14 //Defining min cnpj size 
#define CNPJ_MAX 18 //Defining max cnpj size (unusable)
#define DATE_MIN 8 //Defining min date size
#define DATE_MAX 10 //Defining max date size (unusable)
#define NUMERO_MIN 48 //RAM
#define NUMERO_MAX 57 //RAM

#define DATABASE_TEMP "temp.txt"  //Creating txt to be temperoray database
#define DATABASE_USER "users.txt" //Creating txt to be user database
#define DATABASE_CONTRACT "contrats.txt"  //Creating txt to be contracts database
#define DATABASE_PP "plants.txt" //Creating txt to be plants database


#define NAME_OPT 'n'//Defining name 
#define ID_OPT 'i' //Defining ID 
#define USER_OPT 'u' //Defining user 
#define POWERP_OPT 'p' //Defining plant 
#define CONTRACT_OPT 'c' //Defining contract 

typedef struct {
  char cnpj[SIZ_CNPJ]; //Defining cnpj struct
  char name[SIZ_NAME]; //Defining name struct
  char date[SIZ_DATE]; //Defining date struct
  float mw; //Defining potency struct
} POWERP;

typedef struct {
  char id[SIZ_ID];//Defining id struct
  char name[SIZ_NAME]; //Defining name struct
} USER;

typedef struct {
  char cnpj[SIZ_CNPJ];
  char id[SIZ_ID];
  char date[SIZ_DATE];
  float mw;
} CONTRACT;

void clean() { //Defininf clean screen function
  #if defined(linux) || defined(unix) || defined(APPLE)
    system("clear");
  #endif
  #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    system("cls");
  #endif
  return;
}
int id_check(char id[SIZ_ID]) {
  int aux, cpf[CPF_MIN], cnpj[CNPJ_MIN], confirmation, aux2, idAux[SIZ_ID];
  int tamanhoString = strlen(id);
  confirmation = TRUE;
  if (tamanhoString == CPF_MIN || (tamanhoString == CPF_MAX && !(id[3] >= NUMERO_MIN && id[3] <= NUMERO_MAX))) {
    if (tamanhoString == CPF_MIN) {
      for (aux = 0; aux < CPF_MIN; aux++) {
        cpf[aux] = id[aux] - NUMERO_MIN;
      }
    }

    if (cpf[1] == cpf[0] && cpf[2] == cpf[1] && cpf[3] == cpf[2] &&
        cpf[4] == cpf[3] && cpf[5] == cpf[4] && cpf[6] == cpf[5] &&
        cpf[7] == cpf[6] && cpf[8] == cpf[7] && cpf[9] == cpf[8] &&
        cpf[10] == cpf[9]) {
      confirmation = FALSE;
    }
    if (confirmation == TRUE) { //First digit verification
      for (aux = 0; aux < CPF_MIN; aux++) {
        idAux[aux] = cpf[aux];
      }
      aux2 = 10;
      for (aux = 0; aux < (CPF_MIN - 2); aux++) {
        idAux[aux] *= aux2;
        aux2--;
      }
      aux2 = 0;
      for (aux = 0; aux < (CPF_MIN - 2); aux++) {
        aux2 += idAux[aux];
      }
      aux2 *= 10;
      aux2 %= 11;
      if (aux2 != cpf[9] && !(aux2 == 10 || aux2 == 11)) {
        confirmation = FALSE;
      }
      if ((aux2 == 10 || aux2 == 11) && cpf[9] != 0) {
        confirmation = FALSE;
      }
    }
    if (confirmation == TRUE) { //Second digit verification
      for (aux = 0; aux < CPF_MIN; aux++) {
        idAux[aux] = cpf[aux];
      }
      aux2 = 11;
      for (aux = 0; aux < (CPF_MIN - 1); aux++) {
        idAux[aux] *= aux2;
        aux2--;
      }
      aux2 = 0;
      for (aux = 0; aux < (CPF_MIN - 1); aux++) {
        aux2 += idAux[aux];
      }
      aux2 *= 10;
      aux2 %= 11;
      if (aux2 != cpf[10] && !(aux2 == 10 || aux2 == 11)) {
        confirmation = FALSE;
      }
      if ((aux2 == 10 || aux2 == 11) && cpf[10] != 0) {
        confirmation = FALSE;
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (tamanhoString == CNPJ_MIN || (tamanhoString == CNPJ_MAX && (id[3] >= NUMERO_MIN && id[3] <= NUMERO_MAX))) {
      if (tamanhoString == CNPJ_MIN) {
        for (aux = 0; aux < CNPJ_MIN; aux++) {
          cnpj[aux] = id[aux] - NUMERO_MIN;
        }
      }

      idAux[0] = cnpj[0] * 5;
      idAux[1] = cnpj[1] * 4;
      idAux[2] = cnpj[2] * 3;
      idAux[3] = cnpj[3] * 2;
      idAux[4] = cnpj[4] * 9;
      idAux[5] = cnpj[5] * 8;
      idAux[6] = cnpj[6] * 7;
      idAux[7] = cnpj[7] * 6;
      idAux[8] = cnpj[8] * 5;
      idAux[9] = cnpj[9] * 4;
      idAux[10] = cnpj[10] * 3;
      idAux[11] = cnpj[11] * 2;
      aux2 = 0;
      for (aux = 0; aux < (CNPJ_MIN - 2); aux++) {
        aux2 += idAux[aux];
      }
      aux2 %= 11;
      if (!(aux2 < 2 && cnpj[12] == 0)) {
        aux2 = 11 - aux2;
        if (aux2 != cnpj[12]) {
          confirmation = FALSE;
        }
      } //organizing cnpj
      idAux[0] = cnpj[0] * 6; 
      idAux[1] = cnpj[1] * 5;
      idAux[2] = cnpj[2] * 4;
      idAux[3] = cnpj[3] * 3;
      idAux[4] = cnpj[4] * 2;
      idAux[5] = cnpj[5] * 9;
      idAux[6] = cnpj[6] * 8;
      idAux[7] = cnpj[7] * 7;
      idAux[8] = cnpj[8] * 6;
      idAux[9] = cnpj[9] * 5;
      idAux[10] = cnpj[10] * 4;
      idAux[11] = cnpj[11] * 3;
      idAux[12] = cnpj[12] * 2;
      aux2 = 0;
      for (aux = 0; aux < (CNPJ_MIN - 1); aux++) {
        aux2 += idAux[aux];
      }
      aux2 %= 11;
      if (!(aux2 < 2 && cnpj[13] == 0)) {
        aux2 = 11 - aux2;
        if (aux2 != cnpj[13]) {
          confirmation = FALSE;
        }
      }
    } else {
      confirmation = FALSE;
    }
  }
  return confirmation;
}
int date_check(char data[SIZ_DATE]) { //Get date in int type.
  int day, month, year, aux, bissexto;
  int confirmation = 1;
  aux = strlen(data);
  if (aux == DATE_MIN || aux == DATE_MAX) {
    if (aux == DATE_MIN) {
      day = (data[0] - NUMERO_MIN) * 10;
      day += (data[1] - NUMERO_MIN);
      month = (data[2] - NUMERO_MIN) * 10;
      month += (data[3] - NUMERO_MIN);
      year = (data[4] - NUMERO_MIN) * 1000;
      year += (data[5] - NUMERO_MIN) * 100;
      year += (data[6] - NUMERO_MIN) * 10;
      year += (data[7] - NUMERO_MIN);
    }
    if (aux == DATE_MAX) {
      day = (data[0] - NUMERO_MIN) * 10;
      day += (data[1] - NUMERO_MIN);
      month = (data[3] - NUMERO_MIN) * 10;
      month += (data[4] - NUMERO_MIN);
      year = (data[6] - NUMERO_MIN) * 1000;
      year += (data[7] - NUMERO_MIN) * 100;
      year += (data[8] - NUMERO_MIN) * 10;
      year += (data[9] - NUMERO_MIN);
    }
    if (month > 12 || month < 1) {
      confirmation = FALSE;
      return confirmation;
    } else {
      if(day >29 && month == 1){
        confirmation = FALSE;
        return confirmation;
      }
      if (day == 31) {
        switch (month) {
          case 1: // january
            confirmation = TRUE;
            return confirmation;
            break;
          case 3: // march
            confirmation = TRUE;
            return confirmation;
            break;
          case 5: // may
            confirmation = TRUE;
            return confirmation;
            break;
          case 7: // july
            confirmation = TRUE;
            return confirmation;
            break;
          case 8: // august
            confirmation = TRUE;
            return confirmation;
            break;
          case 10: // october
            confirmation = TRUE;
            return confirmation;
            break;
          case 12: // december
            confirmation = TRUE;
            return confirmation;
            break;
          default:
            confirmation = FALSE;
            return confirmation;
            break;
        }
      }
      if (day > 31 || day < 1) {
        confirmation = FALSE;
        return confirmation;
      } 
    }
  } else {
    confirmation = FALSE;
  }
  return confirmation;
}
int id_check_database(char i[SIZ_ID], char type_base){ //check database
        int n, aux,confirmation;
    char c[MAX_SIZE];
    char info[MAX_SIZE];
    FILE *data_base;
  
    switch (type_base) {
        case POWERP_OPT:
            data_base = fopen(DATABASE_PP, "r");
            if (data_base == NULL) {
            data_base = fopen(DATABASE_PP, "w+");
            }
            fprintf(data_base,"0xxxxxxxxxxxxx\nnome :3\nxxxxxxxx\n1.000000\n");
            break;
        case USER_OPT:
            data_base = fopen(DATABASE_USER, "r");
            if (data_base == NULL) {
            data_base = fopen(DATABASE_USER, "w+");
            }
            fprintf(data_base,"0xxxxxxxxxxxxx\nnome :3\n");
            break;
        case CONTRACT_OPT:
            data_base = fopen(DATABASE_CONTRACT, "r");
            if (data_base == NULL) {
            data_base = fopen(DATABASE_CONTRACT, "w+");
            }
            fprintf(data_base,"0xxxxxxxxxxxxx\n0xxxxxxxxxx\nxxxxxxxx\n1.000000\n");
            break;
        default:
            return -1;
            break;
    }
    if(strlen(i) == CPF_MIN){
        i[CPF_MIN] = '\0';
        // for(aux = 0; aux<CPF_MIN;aux++){
        // i[aux] -= NUMERO_MIN;
        // }
    }
    if(strlen(i) == CPF_MAX && !(i[3]>=NUMERO_MIN && i[3]<=NUMERO_MAX)){
      i[0] = i[0];
      i[1] = i[1];
      i[2] = i[2];
      i[3] = i[4];
      i[4] = i[5];
      i[5] = i[6];
      i[6] = i[8];
      i[7] = i[9];
      i[8] = i[10];
      i[9] = i[12];
      i[10] = i[13];
      i[11] = '\0';
    }
    if(strlen(i) == CNPJ_MIN && (i[3]>=NUMERO_MIN && i[3]<=NUMERO_MAX)){
        i[CNPJ_MIN] = '\0';
        // for(aux = 0; aux<CNPJ_MIN; aux++){
        // i[aux] -= NUMERO_MIN;
        // }
    }
    if(strlen(i) == CNPJ_MAX){
      i[0] = i[0];
      i[1] = i[1];
      i[2] = i[3];
      i[3] = i[4];
      i[4] = i[5];
      i[5] = i[7];
      i[6] = i[8];
      i[7] = i[9];
      i[8] = i[11];
      i[9] = i[12];
      i[10] = i[13];
      i[11] = i[14];
      i[12] = i[16];
      i[13] = i[17];
      i[14] = '\0';
    }
    while(!feof(data_base)){
        fgets(c,100,data_base);
        //printf("\n\"%s\", \"%s\"\n",c,i);
        n = FALSE;
        for(aux = 0; aux < strlen(i); aux++){
          if(i[aux] == '\0'){
            break;
          }
          if(i[aux] != c[aux]){
              n = FALSE;
              break;
          }else{
              n = TRUE;
          }
        }
        if(n == TRUE){
          break;
        }
    }
    if(n == FALSE){
        return FALSE;
    }
    return n;
}
int power_plant_db_add(POWERP pp){ //powerplant add in database
  FILE *data_base; 
  data_base = fopen(DATABASE_PP,"a+");
  fprintf(data_base,"%s\n",pp.cnpj);
  fprintf(data_base,"%s\n",pp.name);
  fprintf(data_base,"%s\n",pp.date);
  fprintf(data_base,"%f\n",pp.mw);
  fclose(data_base);
  puts(":)");
  return 0;
}
int contract_db_add(CONTRACT c){ //add contract to db
  FILE *data_base;
  data_base = fopen(DATABASE_CONTRACT,"a+");
  fprintf(data_base,"%s\n",c.cnpj);
  fprintf(data_base,"%s\n",c.id);
  fprintf(data_base,"%s\n",c.date);
  fprintf(data_base,"%f\n",c.mw);
  fclose(data_base);
  return 0;
}
int user_db_add(USER u){ //add user to db
  FILE *data_base;
  data_base = fopen(DATABASE_USER,"a+");
  fprintf(data_base,"%s\n",u.id);
  fprintf(data_base,"%s\n",u.name);
  fclose(data_base);
  return 0;
}
CONTRACT contract_check(char id[SIZ_ID],int index,char type_check,int reverse){ //check contract
  FILE *data_base;
  CONTRACT con;
  int n, aux,ind;
  data_base = fopen(DATABASE_CONTRACT, "r");
  if (data_base == NULL) {
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_CONTRACT, "w+");
  }
  ind = 0;
  n = FALSE;
  while(!feof(data_base)){
    fscanf(data_base,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n", con.cnpj, con.id, con.date, &con.mw);
    // power plant id check
    if(type_check == POWERP_OPT){
      for(aux = 0; aux < CNPJ_MIN; aux++){
        if(id[aux] == con.cnpj[aux]){
          n = TRUE;
        }else{
          n = FALSE;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    // user id check
    if(type_check == USER_OPT){
      for(aux = 0; aux < strlen(id); aux++){
        if((id[aux] == '\0' || id[aux] == '\n') && con.id[aux-1] == id[aux-1]){
          break;
        }else{
          if(id[aux] == con.id[aux]){
            n = TRUE;
          }else{
            n = FALSE;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if(reverse == FALSE){
      if(n == TRUE && ind == index){
        fclose(data_base);
        return con;
      }else{
        if(n == TRUE){
          ind++;
        }
      }
    }else{
      if(n == FALSE && ind == index){
        fclose(data_base);
        return con;
      }else{
        if(n == FALSE){
          ind++;
        }
      }
    }
    if(feof(data_base)){
      break;
    }
  }
  con.id[0] = 'x';
  con.cnpj[0] = 'x';
  fclose(data_base);
  return con;
}
POWERP power_plant_check(char id[SIZ_ID], int index, int reverse){ //powerplant check
  FILE *data_base;
  POWERP pp;
  char c[MAX_SIZE];
  char mw[FLOAT_SIZE];
  int n, aux, aux1,ind;
  data_base = fopen(DATABASE_PP, "r");
  if (data_base == NULL) {
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_PP, "w+");
  }
  n = FALSE;
  ind = 0;
  while(!feof(data_base)){
    fflush(stdin);
    fflush(stdout);
    //fscanf(data_base,"%s\n%[^\n]s\n%s\n%f\n", pp.cnpj, pp.name, pp.date, &pp.mw);
    fscanf(data_base,"%s\n", pp.cnpj);
    fscanf(data_base,"%[^\n]s\n", pp.name);
    fscanf(data_base,"%s\n", pp.date);
    fscanf(data_base,"%f\n", &pp.mw);
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n\n", pp.cnpj, pp.name, pp.date, pp.mw);
    for(aux = 0; aux < CNPJ_MIN; aux++){
      if(id[aux] == pp.cnpj[aux]){
        n = TRUE;
      }else{
        n = FALSE;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(reverse == FALSE){
      if(n == TRUE && ind == index){
        fclose(data_base);
        return pp;
      }else{
        if(n == TRUE){
          ind++;
        }
      }
    }else{
      if(n == FALSE && ind == index){
        fclose(data_base);
        return pp;
      }else{
        if(n == FALSE){
          ind++;
        }
      }
    }
    if(feof(data_base)){
      break;
    }
  }
  fclose(data_base);
  clean();
  pp.cnpj[0] = 'x';
  return pp;
}
USER user_check(char id[SIZ_ID], int index, int reverse){ //Check user in database functions
  FILE *data_base;
  USER usr;
  char c[MAX_SIZE];
  int n, aux, aux1,ind;
  data_base = fopen(DATABASE_USER, "r");
  if (data_base == NULL) {
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_USER, "w+");
  }
  ind = 0;
  n = FALSE;
  while(!feof(data_base)){
    fflush(stdin); //Cleaning keyboard
    fflush(stdout);//Cleaning keyboard
    fscanf(data_base,"%s\n", usr.id);
    fscanf(data_base,"%[^\n]s\n", usr.name);
    for(aux = 0; aux < strlen(id); aux++){
      if(id[aux] == usr.id[aux]){
        n = TRUE;
      }else{
        n = FALSE;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(feof(data_base)){
      break;
    }
    if(reverse == FALSE){
      if(n == TRUE && ind == index){
        fclose(data_base);
        return usr;
      }else{
        if(n == TRUE){
          ind++;
        }
      }
    }else{
      if(n == FALSE && ind == index){
        fclose(data_base);
        return usr;
      }else{
        if(n == FALSE){
          ind++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fclose(data_base);
  usr.id[0] = 'x';
  return usr;
}
float power_plant_mw_info(char id[SIZ_ID]){
  CONTRACT c;
  POWERP pp;
  int aux = 0;
  pp = power_plant_check(id,0,FALSE);
  float f = pp.mw;
  for(;;){
      c = contract_check(id,aux,POWERP_OPT,FALSE);
      aux++;
      if(c.id[0] == 'x'){
          break;
      }
      pp.mw -= c.mw;
      printf("a %s\n%f\n",c.id,pp.mw);
      clean();
  }
  return pp.mw;
}
void delete_database(char id[SIZ_ID], char type_delete){ //Functions to delete database
  FILE* data_base,*temp;
  CONTRACT con;
  USER usr;
  POWERP pp;
  int aux;
  char c[SIZ_ID],n[MAX_SIZE];
  puts("fase0\n");
  if(type_delete == USER_OPT){
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_USER,"r");
    temp = fopen(DATABASE_TEMP,"w+");
    aux = 0;
    for(;;){
      usr = user_check(id,aux,TRUE);
      printf("%s\n",usr.id);
      if(usr.id[0] == 'x'){
        break;
      }
      puts("fase1\n");
      aux++;
      fprintf(temp,"%s\n%s\n",usr.id,usr.name);
    }
    
    fclose(data_base);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(DATABASE_USER);
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_USER,"a+");
    temp = fopen(DATABASE_TEMP,"r");
    for(;;){
      fscanf(temp,"%s\n%[^\n]s\n",usr.id,usr.name);
      if(feof(temp)){
        break;
      }
      puts("fase2\n");
      fprintf(data_base,"%s\n%s\n",usr.id,usr.name);
    }
    fclose(data_base);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(DATABASE_TEMP);
  }else{
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_PP,"r");
    temp = fopen(DATABASE_TEMP,"w+");
    aux = 0;
    for(;;){
      pp = power_plant_check(id,aux,TRUE);
      printf("%s\n",pp.cnpj);
      if(pp.cnpj[0] == 'x'){
        break;
      }
      puts("fase1\n");
      aux++;
      fprintf(temp,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n",pp.cnpj,pp.name,pp.date,pp.mw);
    }
    fclose(data_base);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(DATABASE_PP);
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_PP,"a+");
    temp = fopen(DATABASE_TEMP,"r");
    for(;;){
      fscanf(temp,"%s\n", pp.cnpj);
      fscanf(temp,"%[^\n]s\n", pp.name);
      fscanf(temp,"%s\n", pp.date);
      fscanf(temp,"%f\n", &pp.mw);
      puts("fase2\n");
      fprintf(data_base,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n",pp.cnpj,pp.name,pp.date,pp.mw);
      if(feof(temp)){
        break;
      }
    }
    fclose(data_base);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(DATABASE_TEMP);
  }
  //Removing contracts
  if(type_delete == USER_OPT){
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_CONTRACT,"r");
    temp = fopen(DATABASE_TEMP,"w+");
    aux = 0;
    for(;;){
      con = contract_check(id,aux,USER_OPT,TRUE);
      printf("%s\n",con.cnpj);
      if(con.id[0] == 'x'){
        break;
      }
      puts("fase1\n");
      aux++;
      fprintf(temp,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n",con.cnpj,con.id,con.date,con.mw);
    }
    
    fclose(data_base);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(DATABASE_CONTRACT);
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_CONTRACT,"a+");
    temp = fopen(DATABASE_TEMP,"r");
    for(;;){
      fscanf(temp,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n",con.cnpj,con.id,con.date,&con.mw);
      if(feof(temp)){
        break;
      }
      puts("fase2\n");
      fprintf(data_base,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n",con.cnpj,con.id,con.date,con.mw);
    }
    fclose(data_base);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(DATABASE_TEMP);
    return;
  }else{
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_CONTRACT,"r");
    temp = fopen(DATABASE_TEMP,"w+");
    aux = 0;
    for(;;){
      con = contract_check(id,aux,POWERP_OPT,TRUE);
      printf("%s\n",con.cnpj);
      if(con.id[0] == 'x'){
        break;
      }
      puts("fase1\n");
      aux++;
      fprintf(temp,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n",con.cnpj,con.id,con.date,con.mw);
    }
    
    fclose(data_base);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(DATABASE_CONTRACT);
    data_base = fopen(DATABASE_CONTRACT,"a+");
    temp = fopen(DATABASE_TEMP,"r");
    for(;;){
      fscanf(temp,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n",con.cnpj,con.id,con.date,&con.mw);
      puts("fase2\n");
      fprintf(data_base,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n",con.cnpj,con.id,con.date,con.mw);
      if(feof(temp)){
        break;
      }
    }
    fclose(data_base);
    fclose(temp);
    remove(DATABASE_TEMP);
    return;
    }

}
```

My problem is making this files in one ".c"
Can someone help me? :)

Comment: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/3502
Link to all .c code.

Comment: Replace the `#include` with the content of the file.

Comment: Cut-and-paste with a GUI editor?

Comment: Literally put everything from the header file in the place of `#include "221037581.h"`. That *is* what an include is.

Comment: You define complete functions in the header file. That is usually a bad idea. There are some exceptions, but even those would normally be `static inline` functions.

Comment: OT: Spotted this while marvelling at all the copy/paste: `fscanf(data_base,"%[^\n]s\n", pp.name);` ... This is not going to do what you want (or, what I expect you want.)

Comment: Worked!
Thx Andrew Henle, KamilCuk, Cheatah. :D
I will check this out, about defining the functions on the header file.
And @Fe2O3, thx, i was leaving blank this error, only now i noticed him :)

Comment: Typically that format string would be `" %[^\n]"`. Also please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) and use the following `fscanf` to control the loop, after deleting every `\n` in its format string. In fact remove every `\n` from every format string.

Comment: You could just send in the result of the precompiler, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900870/can-gcc-output-c-code-after-preprocessing, but I'm not sure if your teacher would not like this either...

Comment: The "header" file contains perhaps hundreds of lines of code, but little to no comments. And those few comments you throw here and there are mostly unnecessary, like `user_db_add` function has a comment just besides it `//add user to db`. Why?.. Your "amazing teacher" might not like this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the #include with the content of the file.
Credits:
@KamilCuk
:D